# UISegmentedControl index

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to list out the selected index of many UISegmentControls. I set 5 of them on 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 respectively, and the result after using this code (in the array) is: 2, 2, 0, 0, 0...

```
for (UISegmentedControl *seg in segmentArray)
{
    NSString* xWrapped = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", seg.selectedSegmentIndex+1];
    [difficultyH addObject: xWrapped];
}
```

Why??

EDIT:

This is how the segments are created:

```
//segment controll

            NSArray *itemArray2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"very easy", @"easy", @"ok", @"hard", @"challenging", nil];
            UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl2 = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray2];
            segmentedControl2.frame = CGRectMake(480, -60, 130, 350);
            segmentedControl2.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
            segmentedControl2.selectedSegmentIndex = val - 1;
            [segmentedControl2 addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlHomework:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

            segmentedControl2.transform =
            CGAffineTransformRotate(segmentedControl2.transform, degreesToRadians(90));

            NSArray *arr = [segmentedControl2 subviews];
            for (int i = 0; i < [arr count]; i++) {
                UIView *v = (UIView*) [arr objectAtIndex:i];
                NSArray *subarr = [v subviews];
                for (int j = 0; j < [subarr count]; j++) {
                    if ([[subarr objectAtIndex:j] isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                        UILabel *l = (UILabel*) [subarr objectAtIndex:j];
                        l.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(- M_PI / 2.0); //do the reverse of what Ben did
                    }
                }
            }

            [image1 addSubview:segmentedControl2];

            segmentedControl2.tag = i;

            [segmentArray addObject: segmentedControl2];

            //segment controll
```

Comment: If you are getting 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, then for sure, you are not setting them to the values you think.

Comment: have you linked function as IBActions to the segment controls

Comment: Well, the values can change, and the segments are created programmably, then added to an array

Comment: How are you setting the selected indexes?  In code or by clicking on them in the UI?

Comment: I tried the code you posted, and it worked fine for me, so the problem is not in this code.

Comment: I set the index in the code first, and then I modyfy it in the user interface( if necessary).